# Check xml imported and exported out of access without any duplicates or missing information

Tags: xml, ms-access, xsd, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I have this xml and xsd file with a lot of data which I have only used the xml to import into access. Not sure what to do with the xsd file. I tried xml mapping in excel using the xsd and xml files but that created duplicates. I tried imported into access that seems to work but I am not sure if there are duplicates or missing information once I export it to a excel file. I tried opening the xml file in notepad++ and using the count function to see if there is the same number of data per tag as there are rows in access table but still not sure. Is there a way to check for that? Is there a better way to view the xml data?

Comment: If you don't know what an XSD file is, you could have Googledand found: https://www.lifewire.com/xsd-file-2622606 You need to clarify your question because we don't know if you want Excel only, or Access then Excel (i.e. I tried xml mapping in excel ... but that created duplicates. I tried imported into access...) Access has the capability to find duplicates - very simple. Missing data? How would you determine that automatically? Each XML grouping should equate to one record.

Comment: Hi Wayne, yeah I googled it and basically found it provided the structure in the xml file for attributes and elements. What I need to know is if I need to use it in access and if just importing the xml file would be sufficient without any duplicates or missing data. I want to compare the xml and the table in access in a way

Comment: Since the XSD is basically a map with no data, do you already have the table defined?   Look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167846(v=office.11).aspx